# Give jQuery created text it's own exclusive properties

Tags: jquery, css, fonts

I created text with jQuery like so:

```
$("#box").append("HelloWorld")
```

I can use CSS and edit the font like so:

```
    #box{

    text-align: center;
    font-size: 80px;
    color: purple;
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-style:italic;

     }
```

But unfortunately this changes the properties of all the text in this Div.

Is there a way to change only this text by giving it an ID of some sort. And then giving properties to only that ID using CSS. Or is there another way? I've tried looking it up but maybe I'm not asking the question correctly.

Even if there was a way to give the text a 'h1', 'h2', or 'p' property that would be perfect.

Thanks for any answers in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to wrap it with another element

```
$("#box").append('<span class="special">HelloWorld</span>') // you can use any element like p, h1, h2, div etc as the wrapper element
```

then

```
#box span.special {
    //custom properties
}
```

Comment: How can you replace 'HelloWorld' with a variable?

Comment: @DennisCallanan `$("#box").append('<span class="special">' + myvar + '</span>')`

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your added element and then add CSS inline styles like this:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ytUGS/

```
var addedElement = $('<span>HelloWorld</span>');
addedElement
    .css('color', 'Red')
    .css('font-weight', 'bold');

$("#box").append(addedElement);
```